# Adding Image extensions through Google ads API

Tags: python, ads, google-ads-api

I am using this script based on the documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/samples/add-image-extension

```
def create_image_extensions(df):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        extension_feed_item_service = 
            client.get_service("ExtensionFeedItemService")
        extension_feed_item_operation = 
            client.get_type("ExtensionFeedItemOperation")
        extension_feed_item = extension_feed_item_operation.create
        extension_feed_item.image_feed_item.image_asset =  
            client.get_service("AssetService").asset_path(account_id, 
                row.asset_id)
        response = extension_feed_item_service.mutate_extension_feed_items(customer_id=account_id, operations=\[extension_feed_item_operation\])
        image_resource_name = response.results\[0\].resource_name
        print("Created an image extension with resource name: "f"'{image_resource_name}'")    
        campaign_extension_setting_service = client.get_service("CampaignExtensionSettingService")
        campaign_extension_setting_operation = client.get_type("CampaignExtensionSettingOperation")
        ces = campaign_extension_setting_operation.create
        ces.campaign = client.get_service("CampaignService").campaign_path(account_id, row.campaign_id)
        ces.extension_type = client.enums.ExtensionTypeEnum.IMAGE
        ces.extension_feed_items.append(image_resource_name)
    
        response = (
            campaign_extension_setting_service.mutate_campaign_extension_settings(
                customer_id=account_id,
                operations=[campaign_extension_setting_operation],
            )
        )
        print("Created a campaign extension setting with resource name: "f"'{response.results[0].resource_name}'")`
```

But running into an error now:

```
Method: /google.ads.googleads.v15.services.ExtensionFeedItemService/MutateExtensionFeedItems, RequestId: B5OFT8TdalKrrmx0lEdMkA, IsFault: True, FaultMessage: Feed-based extension is read-only for this extension type.

error_code {
    feed_error: LEGACY_EXTENSION_TYPE_READ_ONLY
  }
  message: "Feed-based extension is read-only for this extension type."
```

Comment: Google has pretty poor documentation for this as well. I tried reaching out to their support and hardly getting in concrete response. Let me know if you are at some point time able to figure it out